# What does the single-right-arrow (→) mean for collections in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

When I use auto-complete on lists on InteliJ, it shows a single-right-arrow, with no documentation on what it means. It looks like →. In an example, it's called as:

```
val sampleList: List[String] = List("a", "b", "c");
sampleList.→()
```

I don't know what goes in the parenthesis, I can't use it like a spark map either, so doing `s => s` shows an error. And on the Scala documentation [online](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html), the arrow operator isn't listed.

This is how it shows up on the auto-complete
[image]

What would be an example usage of this arrow operator?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`->` isn't defined specifically on collections, it's defined on `Any` (via the implicit class `ArrowAssoc`). You can see its definition in [Predef.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L307).

It is an alternative syntax for creating a `Tuple2`:

```
scala> 1 -> 2
res0: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> List().->(2)
res1: (List[Nothing], Int) = (List(),2)

scala> (1 -> 2) == ((1, 2))
res2: Boolean = true
```